# Arcpy Subtracting rasters error - TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: arcpy, raster, typeerror

I have a script which subtracts 2 versions of the same raster from each other (one newer than the other) and then extracts the additions & deletions that have happened.

I created a simple test script which works:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")


# Local variables:
New = "C:\\Data\\JOB_13\\tq03\\ABRdsText.tif"
Old = "D:\\Data\\Job_Backups\\JOB_13\\tq03\\ABRdsText.tif"
Addition_Raster = "C:\\Testing\\District_Editor\\QC_ChangePlots\\JOB_13\\tq03\\Additions\\output.tif"
Deletion_Raster = "C:\\Testing\\District_Editor\\QC_ChangePlots\\JOB_13\\tq03\\Deletions\\output.tif"

arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(New, "N")
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(Old, "O")


# Process: Raster Calculator
RR = Raster("N") - Raster("O")

# Process: Extract by Attributes
arcpy.gp.ExtractByAttributes_sa(RR, "VALUE =-255 OR VALUE =0", Addition_Raster)

# Process: Extract by Attributes (2)
arcpy.gp.ExtractByAttributes_sa(RR, "VALUE =255 or VALUE=0", Deletion_Raster
```

I then replicated this into my main script:

```
#import the necessary modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os

#Checkout the necessary Arc licences
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

#Ask the user for the job number
#Job_Number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# MANUAL OVERIDE TO GET TEST JOB_NUMBER
Job_Number = 13
Job = 'JOB_'+str(Job_Number)

####################################################
#Folder where all data will be written to
OutputsDirectory = r"C:\Testing\District_Editor\QC_ChangePlots"

####################################################
#Folder with the backed up data pre-editing i.e. old data
BackupDirectory =r"D:\Data\Job_Backups"

####################################################
#Location of the QC Change plot Master mxd
ChangePlot_mxd = r"Y:\esriuk\OSBurnProcessGPTools\resources\mxdHolder\QC_ChangePlot.mxd"

####################################################
#Location of the Job folder
DataFolder = os.path.join("C:\\Data\\",Job)

####################################################

JobF = os.path.join(OutputsDirectory,Job)

for folder in os.listdir(DataFolder):
    arcpy.env.workspace = DataFolder + "\\" + str(folder)
    Ras = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
    for Raster in Ras:
        #Set the output rasters
        Additions = os.path.join(JobF + "\\" + str(folder) + "\\Additions\\"+ str(Raster))
        Deletions = os.path.join (JobF + "\\" + str(folder) + "\\Deletions\\"+ str(Raster))

        #Set the file paths for the new and old rasters
        New = os.path.join(str(DataFolder) +"\\" + str(folder) + "\\" + str(Raster))
        Old = os.path.join(str(BackupDirectory) + "\\" + str(Job) + "\\" + str(folder) + "\\" + str(Raster))

        #Convert the Raster datasets into a temporary Raster Layer so that they can be used for a calculaion
        arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(New, "N")
        arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(Old, "O")


        #Raster Calculator - subtract the old raster from the new raster ( new - old)
        CalculatedRast = Raster("N") - Raster("O")



        #Extract the Additions
        arcpy.gp.ExtractByAttributes_sa(CalculatedRast, "VALUE =-255 OR VALUE =0", Additions)


        #Extract the deletions
        arcpy.gp.ExtractByAttributes_sa(CalculatedRast, "VALUE =255 or VALUE=0", Deletions)
```

However, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "S:\Development\Dan\GIS\Code\District_Editor\QC_ChangePlots.py", line 204, in <module>
    CalculatedRast = Raster("N") - Raster("O")
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Anybody able to suggest where I am going wrong and how to fix it?  I'm fairly new to python, so it's probably something quite simple!

The error seems to be here

```
CalculatedRast = Raster("N") - Raster("O")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make the addition and subtraction rasters as raster objects as shown in the latter example of the help files [Subtracting rasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m000000mn000000)

Comment: isn't that already happening within the calculation? As I'm stating Raster("N") - Raster ("O")
I have just tried creating 2 new variables
NR = Raster("N")
OR - Raster ("O")
and then replacing these values in the calculation, but still no luck.  I get the same error.

Comment: don't see it then

Comment: I've just figured it out.  In my For statement I'm saying
For Raster in Ras.  Arcpy then tries to call on "Raster" to convert the file path strings to rasters, but it calls my variable instead.